# Flutter read local Json from assets

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to understand how to work with Json in Flutter/Dart.

I want to read a local Json from the assets folder and display it on the screen.

I have in the assets folder the following Json

```
{
  "title": [
    {
      "number": 8,
      "firstarray": [
        26.6, 27, 26.6, 22.9, 27.1, 26.8, 

      ],
      "secondarray": [
        26.6, 27, 26.6, 22.9, 27.1, 26.8, 
      ]
    },
    {
      "number": 9,
      "firstarray": [
        26.6, 27, 26.6, 22.9, 27.1, 26.8, 
      ],
      "secondarray": [
        26.6, 27, 26.6, 22.9, 27.1, 26.8, 
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to created a Class "DataModel" to be able to read from JSON file.

```
class DataModel {
  DataModel({this.measure});

  List<DataTitle>? measure;

  factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataModel(
      measure: List<DataTitle>.from(
          json['title'].map((c) => DataTitle.fromJson(c)).toList()),
    );
  }
}

class DataTitle {
  DataTitle(
      {required this.number,
      required this.firstarray,
      required this.secondarray});

  int? number;
  List<double>? firstarray;
  List<double>? secondarray;

  DataTitle.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    number = json['number'];
    firstarray = json['firstarray'] == null
        ? []
        : List<double>.from(json['firstarray'].map((x) => x.toDouble()));
    secondarray = json['secondarray'] == null
        ? []
        : List<double>.from(json['secondarray'].map((x) => x.toDouble()));
  }
}
```

and I am trying to read and print to the console as follows.

```
  Future loadData() async {
    String jsonString = await _loadData();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    DataTitle measure = DataTitle.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    print('${measure.number} - ${measure.firstarray} - ${measure.secondarray}');
  }
```

I get at the console printed out,

```
flutter: null - [] - []
```

but i was expecting

```
flutter:  8 -  26.6, 27, 26.6, 22.9, 27.1, 26.8 - 26.6, 27, 26.6, 22.9, 27.1, 26.8,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated part:

You tried to convert the whole json structure to an object of your `DataModel` class. However, in your json, only the list which is under the `title` node contains `DataModel`objects.

Please check the `loadData` function below, where I first extract the list out of the `title` node and then make one `DataModel` object for each element in the list.

```dart
class DataModel {
  DataModel({this.measure});

  List<DataTitle>? measure;

  factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataModel(
      measure: List<DataTitle>.from(
          json['title'].map((c) => DataTitle.fromJson(c)).toList()),
    );
  }
}

class DataTitle {
  DataTitle(
      {required this.number,
      required this.firstarray,
      required this.secondarray});

  int? number;
  List<double>? firstarray;
  List<double>? secondarray;

  DataTitle.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    number = json['number'];
    firstarray = json['firstarray'] == null
        ? []
        : List<double>.from(json['firstarray'].map((x) => x.toDouble()));
    secondarray = json['secondarray'] == null
        ? []
        : List<double>.from(json['secondarray'].map((x) => x.toDouble()));
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'DataTitle{number: $number, firstarray: $firstarray, secondarray: $secondarray}';
  }
}

Future loadData() async {
  final jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');
  final decodedJson = json.decode(jsonString);
  List<DataTitle> dataTileList= (decodedJson ['title'] as List)
      .map((jsonElement) => DataTitle.fromJson(jsonElement))
      .toList();
  print(dataTileList.first);
  print(dataTileList.last);
}
```

---

## Original Answer

In your code your json data example does not match the way you try to read it. You provide a single element but you try to read a list of elements.

## If the json data contains a single element

Your json structure is of type `Map<String, dynamic>` so this is the data type which `json.decode` returns (or you also use the method `jsonDecode` from `import 'dart:convert';`).

You then try to cast this `Map` to `List<dynamic>`which obviously fails.

Instead, the first part should look like this:

```dart
    final jsonString =
        await rootBundle.rootBundle.loadString('assets/measurelist.json');
    final json = json.decode(jsonString) as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

Afterwards you need to call the `fromJson`method of your data model class.

In your example you try to use `map` to create one object for each element in the json array. However, in your example json you only have one object which is not part of an array. So that `map` doesn't make sense.

What should work is directly calling the `fromJson` method on the single data element you provide, like:

```dart
   return DataModel.fromJson(json);
```

Putting all together, your method should look like this:

```dart
  Future<DataModel> readJsonData() async {
    final jsonString =
        await rootBundle.rootBundle.loadString('assets/measurelist.json');
    final json = json.decode(jsonString) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return DataModel.fromJson(json);
  }
```

## If the json data contains a list of elements

If your datamodel actually contains a list of elements, the json data would look something like this:

```json
[
{
  "title": [
    {
      "number": 8,
      "firstarray": [
        26.6, 27, 26.6, 2, 27.1, 26.8, 26.6, 26.8, 26.8, 27.2, 26.9, 0, 26.8,
        26.8, 26.9, 0, 27.1, 26.8, 27.2, 26.7
      ],
      "secondarray": [
        0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 6.4, 6.4, 2.1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 6.3
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "title": [
    {
      "number": 9,
      "firstarray": [
        26.6, 27, 26.6, 2, 27.1, 26.8, 26.6, 26.8, 26.8, 27.2, 26.9, 0, 26.8,
        26.8, 26.9, 0, 27.1, 26.8, 27.2, 26.7
      ],
      "secondarray": [
        0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 6.4, 6.4, 2.1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 6.3
      ]
    }
  ]
},

...

]
```

Then your method for parsing it should look something like this:

```dart
  Future<List<DataModel>> readJsonData() async {
    final jsonString =
        await rootBundle.rootBundle.loadString('assets/measurelist.json');
    final listOfJsonElements = json.decode(jsonString) as List;
    return listOfJsonElements.map((jsonElement) => DataModel.fromJson(jsonElement)).toList();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help.  I was following your sugestions, but now i have another problem. When i try to display the values on the screen, i get a error saying that "The getter 'number' isn't defined for the type 'DataModel'". And this error is for the 3 values. I changed my post to the actual state that i have right now.

Comment: still seems to be an inconsistency with your data models and the way you define your data and try to read it. I don't have much time right now, but the error says that `DataModel` class doesn't have a getter `number`. That is correct, your second class `Title` only has a field named `number`.

Apparently you try to read the field `number` from a `DataModel` object but you should read it from a `Title` object.

A suggestion: Try to set breakpoints at important lines, or print some values to the console to check if they are in the format that you expect

Comment: Sorry to come back to ask for help. I follow your suggestion trying to print out some values. I  refactor my code without any error message. At this moment i try only to print out to the console instead to the screen. Unfortunately it dos not give me what i was expecting .

Comment: no worries. You are actually pretty close. You just missed one step. I tried your recent code, made a small adjustment and it's working now. For debugging purposes I also added a `toString` method to your class. Please check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I checked your updated answer and tried it out. IT IS WORKING... :). It was very very helpful your suggestions. I need to put my head more around this Json & Map topic in Dart and Flutter. Again, Thanks for your help.

Comment: you're welcome, nice to hear that you got it working

Answer (score 1):

Fix your model and future void:

**DataModel**

```
class DataModel {
  List<Title>? title;

  DataModel({this.title});

  DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['title'] != null) {
      title = <Title>[];
      json['title'].forEach((v) {
        title!.add(new Title.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.title != null) {
      data['title'] = this.title!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Title {
  int? number;
  List<double>? firstarray;
  List<int>? secondarray;

  Title({this.number, this.firstarray, this.secondarray});

  Title.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    number = json['number'];
    firstarray = json['firstarray'].cast<double>();
    secondarray = json['secondarray'].cast<int>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['number'] = this.number;
    data['firstarray'] = this.firstarray;
    data['secondarray'] = this.secondarray;
    return data;
  }
}
```

**Function**

```
Future<DataModel> readJsonData() async {
    final jsondata = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/measurelist.json');
    final list = json.decode(jsondata) as Map<String, dynamic> ;
    DataModel res = DataModel.fromJson(list);
    return res;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help.  I was following your sugestions, but now i have another problem. When i try to display the values on the screen, i get a error saying that "The getter 'number' isn't defined for the type 'DataModel'". And this error is for the 3 values. I changed my post to the actual state that i have right now.